# Blender to unreal engine

Tags: uv, export, blender-internal-render-engine, normals, unreal-engine

Here's my video made with blender and unreal engine:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPkYeqT0Jyg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HG3--iTjPq0

I have a problem with plane meshes and I don't know weather it has something to do with Unreal engine or Blender. I need double sided lighting that plane would be displayed on both sides. And even if I select double sided in Unreal engine I still have transparent walls, floors and ceiling so I have to use solid shapes which takes much more time in building lighting and baking maps. For example I model a flower and I don't want to use solidify modifier but then when I export it to Unreal engine and I can't find backface culling option there and I can only see one side of leaf.  [the tree is taken from another unreal project and i have no idea how they made it.]

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean but for double-sided foliage see here: https://goo.gl/KKLB3q

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the normals. Game engines will always display on only the side where the normals are pointing out. As far as I know, Blender does not allow  double sided normals, so make two planes, one for each side.

Comment: helix, blender doesn't allow for double sided normal, but the option "backface culling" enables the rendering of both sides. he is asking how to enable this in unity

Answer (score 1):

1) Set up material in UE4.
2) Open it.
3) Select 'Double-sided' on the panel at the left.